# Configure java spring boot to read JSP files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

Does anybody know how to configure java spring boot to read JSP files? The methods which are on the internet is not working for me. I have already added tomcat jasper dependency to porm.xml.

My JSP file:`home.jsp`,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
I love java
</body>
</html>
```

Added dependancies in `PORM.XML`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

My controller:`HomeController.java`

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("home")
    @ResponseBody
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("hi");
        return "home.jsp";
    }
}
```

Please explain what is the problem here?. I'm using STS IDE. Adding tomcat jasper is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@ResponseBody` from your controller method

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("home")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("hi");
        return "home.jsp";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Plese can you explain what @ResponseBody does ?

Comment: @Mr.Semicolon `@ResponseBody` uses the returned value (in this case `home.jsp`) as the response of the request. That means that if you open `/home`, you'll see `"home.jsp"` as a text. This can be useful for developing REST services. On the other hand, if you don't use `@ResponseBody`, the returned value should be a view (or a model + a view), and in that case, the specific JSP is parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Use Model and View to return jsp page.

In the below code the **List is the name of the jsp page.**

```
@RequestMapping( value="/dataCreate", method = {RequestMethod.POST })
        public ModelAndView createTemplate(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        {
            MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
            MultipartFile cuscsvfile = multipartRequest.getFile("cuscsvfile");
            ModelAndView modelView=new ModelAndView("redirect:list");
            String templateName = request.getParameter("templateName");
            String msg = messageSource.getMessage("new.template.creation.success", new Object[]{templateName}, Locale.ENGLISH);
            modelView.addObject("msg", msg);
            //return "redirect:/list";
            return modelView;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
```

And return the jsp names without extension, e.g. "home" instead of "home.jsp"

Answer (score 1):

Remove **@ResponseBody** annotation and update your **application.properties** file with the following values

**spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/**

**spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp**

Answer (score -1):

Try with it, you can return without .jsp.

```
@RequestMapping("home")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("hi");
        return "home";
    }
```

To do that we have to do some configurations in `application.properties` file,

```
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

(But this is not the exact answer for the question below. This is just an idea of how you can modify the code.)

Comment: Nope! 404 error occurred for me after removing  .jsp

Comment: Sorry, not 404 error. Its include a white-label error page. I can't understand whats the meaning of that